# How are Profile Patterns calculated during a visit?

Tags: xdb, user-profile

For a customer, we are using Profiles and Paterns to segment visitors.

In the attached screenshot from the Experience Profile, we see something strange in the data:

- The sum of the values in the spider chart does not match what is calculated in the paterns.
- In the spider chart, we see a clear interest towards Flights, but the pattern-match evens out around 25% for each pattern.
- Roundtrips gathered 0 points, but the Roundtrip pattern matches almost 24%.

Any suggestions on how to explain this data?

Releated questions:

- If a visitor visits the same page multiple times during a visit, is it calculated multiple times in the Profile score?

[image]

Screenshots of Profile cards:

[image]

[image][image][image]

Comment: It also depends on how the Profile Cards are configured. Can you also make a screenshots of them? Btw here is a good explanation - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/55/how-does-sitecore-match-a-pattern-card-for-personalization.

Comment: Hi Tamas, thank you for replying and the link. I have attached the profiles in the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Sitecore "match" a pattern card for personalization?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/55/how-does-sitecore-match-a-pattern-card-for-personalization)

Comment: @techphoria414 I think the two questions are very similar, but I also think that the wording of this question may lead to some additional insight that goes deeper into the calculation and matching formulas that may be useful, as well. I'm glad you marked it as a possible duplicate, so that the two posts are linked, but I am also voting to keep this post open.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your related question, if a person visits the same page multiple times during a visit, each time should count as a separate hit to that page and be included in the calculation in that manner.